# Having to manually reload page when switching pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made a Navbar component along with the pages. Home.jsx and About.jsx each link to their appropriate pages after a **Refresh** of the page.

I have tried to look on other documents on stackoverflow and I can find really anything about this issue. I also have tried using Javascripts

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

function but that does not seem to work. Can anyone help me out on this?

Here is my app.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import Home from "./Components/Pages/Home/Home";
import About from "./Components/Pages/About/About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";



function App() {



  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Router>
        <div className="pages">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
      </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Styles/Navbar.css'
import  {BrowserRouter , NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'


function Navbar() {

  const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className='nav-container'>
        <div className='nav-wrapper'>
            <div className='nav-logo'>
                <h1>SapphireServers</h1>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-server"></i>
            </div>
            <div className="nav-link-wrapper">
            <ul className={click ? "nav-menu active" : "nav-menu"}>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                to="/"
                activeClassName="active"
                className="nav-links"
                onClick={handleClick}
              >
                Home
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                exact to="/about" relative='path' activeClassName="active" className="nav-links"onClick={handleClick}  >
                About
              </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
              <a href="https://dash.sapphireservers.net"  activeClassName="Active" className='nav-links'>Sign-Up</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
          <div className="nav-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            <i className={click ? "fas fa-times" : "fas fa-bars"}></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: React Router is pretty much the standard for routing in React.  Their docs are very good too.  If you still need help, we will need to see a lot more code than that single line you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check React Router project, check the documentation and let me know if it helps. Keek going

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).